# Canon EOS 1200D gives shaky star shots

Tags: canon, astrophotography, shutter

I have a Canon EOS 1200D/Rebel T5. I'm an amateur phtographer and still learning. After reading a lot about astrophotography, I tried my hand at it. I took a trip to a relatively dark place, set up on a tripod, and started taking shots using my phone connected to the USB port as a remote release/intervalometer. I took 100 shots at different places, under different conditions. Every single shot, no matter  whether the stars are completely in focus or not, showed a sort of streaking in random directions (not star trailing. I used the 600 rule).
Here are some examples:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B802HQPuk5MlRTJJZEJfM2Z3REU

I have a suspicion that this shaking is being caused by the camera shutter itself. I've tried searching online for others with the same problem, but my Google-fu hasn't helped so far.
Is this some kind of issue with the 1200D or is it just my camera?

P.S. Note that since I have low reputation, I can't post more than 2 links. I'll make a Google Drive folder containing a few more examples if anyone wants, and  I've edited out the links in the question itself.

Comment: Are you using the shutter delay function? (The shutter will only release two seconds _after_ the mirror flips up)? Note that I don't know if your model even offers this.

Comment: @Aganju I used the 2-second delay timer sometimes, and the 10 second delay timer sometimes, but all the images have this distortion/shake.

Comment: After reading further, it seems having Mirror lock-up prevents this sort of thing, and is advertised as a feature with the 2-second timer on the dpreview site [link] (https://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/slrs/canon_eos1200d/specifications), however, people cannot seem to agree on whether this is the same as LiveView. And some of the shots were framed in LiveView both on camera and over USB, but they all have the shake.

Comment: Just some thoughts: How long were your exposures? How sturdy is your tripod, and did you weight it down? What sort of head does the tripod have? Did you allow your kit to cool down to ambient temperature? It can take a least 30 minutes.

Comment: What is the shutter time on those images?  Also how was the camera set up (tripod, height, head type etc.). Also was it windy that night?  My thinking is that the camera wasn't secure enough in the mounting.  Also what was the tripod anchored to and does the lens have an IS/VR system?  But we'll need more info to say for sure.

Comment: @Mick and James Snell exposures were all 15 seconds, aperture was at f/3,5. ISO 1600. All images were shot with these settings. Some images were shot with the camera placed on a rock. Some images were shot with the tripod. I removed the camera strap to prevent swinging. I used multiple tripod heights and angles. It was occasionally windy. Basically, all the photos were shot with a mix of conditions, and the common denominator was that these motion streaks were present every time, although sometimes the stars are out of focus, so for those images I can't say.

Comment: @James Check my comment above.

Comment: It is almost certainly mirror shake. You need to use mirror lock-up if you have it. Alternatively, set a longer exposure and control the exposure manually by covering the lens with something and gently removing it while the mirror is up.

Comment: @salmonlawyer, there is a difference between 2-second-_timer_ and 2-second-_mirror-lockup_. Basically the Mirror moves up and then the camera waits for the vibrations to end, before it takes the shot. _Timer_ only means that the shot is taken in two seconds - without locking the mirror up - so you still have the vibrations, just two seconds later

Comment: @Mick I hadn't thought of covering the lens while exposing initially, but does the same occur when the mirror drops down after a shot? There's no mirror lock up that I can see in the settings or perceive in shots, even though they say it's there. Thanks for the last tip though. But is that the answer? Isn't shutter shock supposed to be limited to shorter exposures?

Comment: @Aganju, like I said, there's no lockup setting, and the DPReview site says that the 2-second timer gives mirror lock up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation (a couple of months after asking the question), I discovered that it was, indeed, the fault of the Canon lens. Basically, I have the older lenses with a weirdly buggy version of Image Stabilisation.

What happened is that the IS on these lenses keeps trying to correct for movement, even when there may be none. I tested it indoors by exposing for a long time in a semi-dark room and focusing on specular highlights on an object (reflections of light on a shiny surface). With IS enabled, I saw weird drift in the highlights. With IS off, there was no drift at all.

I successfully managed to take photos of the galactic center by disabling IS. They may not be great(focusing issues which can't be helped), but it was fun to take them anyway. I forgot to answer my question though. I hope anyone who is still following this question forgives me for this. Sorry!

Comment: You generally shouldn't use image stabilization when shooting on a tripod.

Comment: @EricShain Thing is, it was always on by default, and I hadn't turned it off till that point. Still a camera newb here. Sorry...

Comment: Defaulting on is generally a good idea since most people shoot handheld.

Answer (score 4):

Just my opinion, but mirror slap and MLU issues don't tend to create as much motion as I'm seeing in your second shot. I'd suspect the issue to be more with your tripod or tripod technique. You may also want to check that you're not inadvertently tugging on the USB cable that's connecting your phone to your camera whenever you take an exposure.

A small, tippy four-segment tripod, like the Velbon I habitually use, sucks for longer exposure work, particularly in any kind of wind. I tend to use my Velbon for 360-pano work, because it's small, light, and portable and I'm generally shooting in daylight with fast shutter speeds or indoors without any wind. But when it comes to night-time shooting, I drag out my big heavy three-segment Manfrotto, which is far more stable, and has a ballhead that can actually lock securely and support the weight of my EF 400mm f/5.6 + 5dMkII without any bounce or drifting.

If you're using a telephoto lens that has a lens collar, use the collar. This will definitely help minimize "bouncing" of the lens/camera combination by putting the majority of the weight at the balance point.

If the lens has IS, make sure that if you turn it on, that the lens's IS version is compatible with tripod use (the first generation of IS Canon put in its lenses introduced more shake when used on a tripod).

With a tripod, the lower to the ground you want to go, the more stable the set-up usually is. Having the head extended, or the legs fully-extended may be introducing some instability. If it has a hook, add weight to the center column. If you can spread the legs out at a wider angle, consider doing that.

Also, when you calculated the 600 rule, *did you include the crop factor?*

Just me, but I'd say, first off, test your tripod technique indoors. If you're still getting blur/shake, then maybe it's time to look at the camera.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I'd noticed the issue at the very start of the shoot. I kept the camera on multiple flat surfaces such as rocks, all to get the same result. The tripod I have is cheap, sure, but it doesn't sway or shift when I lock it tight. So far, no shake when shooting indoors. I also made sure the USB cable had maximum slack. Besides, I was using the 18-55 lens, which doesn't add much weight. Also, I had tried some of your suggestions during the shoot. The tripod doesn't have a hook, but I had minimum extension, widest leg settings, etc., all to no avail.

Comment: I also forgot to add that I'd read that the 600 rule applies to APS-C sensors, while the 500 rule applies to full frame.

Comment: @salmonlawyer. To me, if it's fine indoors and bad outdoors with identical technique/settings, then it's probably a technique/environment issue and not the camera. Are _you_ moving about or touching the camera during the exposure? Did you try using just the timer instead of the phone to trigger the shutter or a regular cable release/remote?

Comment: I can't tag inkista for some reason, but, I did think that might be the issue, so I put it in 10 second timer and released the shutter several times.One of the images in the link is from that set as well, though I'm not sure which, since most of the exposures are of the same spot of sky. I'm not sure if I did so in live view, now that I think of it. Could it be that just because I didn't put it live view, that this issue could be occurring??

Comment: @salmonlawyer Doesn't seem likely. My guess is still that it's a tripod-stability issue. You're going to need to narrow down your testing, and keep better notes/records while you shoot in this debugging/learning phase. When you're testing indoors, is _everything_ else identical to what you did while you were out night shooting? (e.g., iso/aperture/shutter speed, how you release the shutter, focal length, lens, etc?)

Comment: You're right. I think I need to start a test and do a test run with notes, but I don't think it'll be possible as of now; I have exams coming up. Would you be willing to wait a week or so later, when I can run some tests?

Answer (score 0):

From the shape of the star trails in your photos, and given the fact that you have a relatively short exposure time, I am almost certain that the problem is caused by mirror shake. With longer exposures, the "trails" caused by mirror shake will be much less noticeable. However, with short exposures (and 12 seconds is a short exposure in astronomical terms), the period during which the camera is vibrating represents a larger percentage of the total exposure time, and any star "trails" caused by mirror shake will be more evident.

One way to overcome this problem is to set a much longer exposure time on the camera and control the exposure yourself by covering the lens with something suitable and then gently removing the cover and replacing it after the required exposure period while the mirror is up. You need to allow plenty of time for any vibrations to die down. Remember that the mirror movement will cause the whole set-up to vibrate.

Do not use the lens cap as the cover. You need something that will cover the front part of the lens and that you can leave sitting on the lens. A plastic container of some sort painted matt black on the inside would be ideal. You could possibly even use a dense black cloth. All you need is something that will keep light out and that you can gently remove and replace without disturbing the camera.

Let's say that you want to make 15-second exposure. Set your camera for 60 seconds (if you can). That will give you plenty of time to do what you need to do. Press the shutter release and immediately lift the cover off the lens but keep it covering the lens. Allow 15 seconds for any vibrations to die down and then remove the cover completely. After the required exposure time, introduce the cover again and wait for the shutter to close. If all goes well, you should have a vibration-free image.

Comment: The first example may be only mirror vibration, but the second example has a lot more than just mirror slap going on!

Comment: Why go to the trouble of covering the lens? You can get a wired shutter release for about $5-10, set the camera to mirror lockup, and then wait up to 30 seconds between the time you lock up the mirror and the time you release the shutter.

Comment: I had thought about a mis-aligned star tracker (or astronomical mounting), but the OP doesn't mention that at all. Also, he mentions the "600 rule", which implies a static mount.

Comment: @MichaelClark If a wired release is possible with the mirror locked up, then that is obviously the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelClark You may be right. The whole set-up may have been moved when the second exposure was taken. We really need to see more examples.

Comment: I don't have time right now to look up the 1200D User Manual and I've never used a 1200D, but I've yet to come across an EOS camera that doesn't allow you to lock up the mirror and use the shutter/wired remote in Bulb mode. Sometimes Bulb is on the mode dial, sometimes it is found as the "longest" shutter time under Tv or M mode. If you can get mirror lockup in bulb mode, then a cheap wired intervalometer can be used to set the shutter time.

Comment: Live View is always mirror locked up unless you've selected "Quick Focus" which drops the mirror long enough to do PDAF and then raises it and immediately takes the picture. But one would think anyone doing astrophotography will have AF turned completely off... The issue with using LV for astrophotography is heat buildup in the sensor.

Comment: I disagree,mirror lockup should have no discernible impact on a 15s exposure. There isn't enough exposure over the time of the mirror movement to impact the photo.

Comment: Live View is true mirror lockup as long as you don't use quick focus.

Comment: @Mick , I had no tracker. It was a static mount on a tripod. Like I said, there is no mirror lock up anywhere in the 1200D settings. I tested the camera and found that LiveView causes the mirror cradle to swing up and stay up when the shutter release is pressed. However, you can still hear a distinct whirr when the shutter releases, even with the lens off. I see no mechanical aperture covering the sensor, so I assume that the mirror cradle motor is still actuating for a second when the shutter releases. I don't know if that's the case, but it seems possible.

Comment: @salmonlawyer We are beginning to think that you may have disturbed the camera or tripod in the second image. You said in your OP "Every single shot ... showed a sort of streaking in random directions." We would all like to see more pictures and I would be very interested if you have any examples where the streaking is in different directions in the **same** image. Some full resolution crops would be useful so we can see maximum detail. Also, I would like to know more about your tripod and mount. Make, model numbers and a photo would be useful. Update your OP if you would, please.

Comment: @Mick The streaking is not in random directions in one image, the streaking is random for all images and is a constant per image, i.e. all objects streak in the same direction, but each photo seems to have random streaking from it's neighbor. I'll edit my question to add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Stars are super distant: If an object’s distance is more than 3000 times its diameter, it appears as a point.  A 10mm coin viewed from 30,000mm (30 meters / 100 feet) appears to the unaided eye as a point with no discernible dimension.

All stars thus appear as pinpoints of light. As starlight filters through earth’s atmosphere, it must pass through different densities of moving air currents. This action causes the star to appear to change its position. In other words, the light rays from a star are caused to zigzag. This is called scintillation.  Scintillation plus camera vibrations and optical inaccuracies are the culprit.

Comment: Your explanation does not account for the fact that all the star trails are the same shape and size, and are aligned in the same direction. How can scintillation (which is a real but random phenomenon) cause this?

Comment: @ Mick -- Of course you are right! Just chalk this up to an old man’s rumblings.

Comment: Do the star trails look like coma (or some other lens distortion)?

Comment: Coma is a monochromatic aberration related to spherical aberration. Coma is independent of aperture and never occurs on axis, always in the field. The coma is actually a series rings much like Newton rings.  However the rings are incomplete and only about 16% of the circle is seen. These partial circles blend together forming a  hard central spot with a tail like a comet. I think this is not coma, just vibration during exposure.